# Optimizing query with or

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a need to join together three tables. The first one has ~100k rows, the second one ~300k rows and the last one ~40 rows. The first and second should be joined by a composite condition, but here's the trick. The query requires it to be a `OR` condition. The indexes can't be properly used because of the OR-condition. I tried separating the two difficult tables to two separate queries and joining them with union to help mysql find proper indexes.

What can I do optimize this query?

```
select * from a, b, c where (a.x = b.x OR a.y = b.y) and b.z = c.z
```

Comment: first thing I would do is move your join conditions to a join ON condition instead of a where clause

Comment: I'm not sure and can't try it out now, but I would check if it helps to just separate the 2 different variations?

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk I'd like to see a proof, that writing all column names is really faster.

Comment: @tombom Just use common sense. Select a single column versus all of them and see how much time it takes for the result to be transported over the network.

Comment: True, but if you need all columns anyway it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @tombom It doesn't if you do need all columns; but that's rarely the case.

Comment: @tombom - While I wouldn't want to use SELECT * in a live system, I wouldn't expect a massive difference in performance from avoiding using it. My concern is when the table gets changed. At least if a specified column disappears the database will object loudly, but with a SELECT * you will may well be left with the SQL working fine but getting some very hard to find (or even notice) errors.

Comment: @tombom Kickstart Well, [here are the stats](http://i.imgur.com/eKQZxcg.png) that it takes longer to retrieve the data. Trials 1, 2 vs 3, 4

Comment: Without the details of the benchmark, and what is meant by the rows it is difficult to know what to make of it. Client execution time difference is insignificant. Client processing time difference is ludicrously large (a factor of about 200). While the data returned is about 100 times greater (entirely possible if one of the columns is something like a BLOB). In normal use I would expect a nominal difference, but for live I would avoid it but for other reasons.

Comment: The * was naturally just for the example. In the real query I better projection

Answer (score 0):

Try a UNION of 2 queries:-

```
select * 
from a
INNER JOIN b ON a.x = b.x
INNER JOIN c ON and b.z = c.z
UNION
select * 
from a
INNER JOIN b ON a.y = b.y
INNER JOIN c ON and b.z = c.z
```

(and in a real application I agree not to use SELECT *)

Comment: Tried something similar to this. I tried simplifying so that I'll leave c out, but the performance was still abysmal

Comment: This is the normal way to allow MySQL to use indexes when there is an OR. If it is still performing badly then it suggests that the indexes it has chosen may be poor. Could you post an EXPLAIN or you version of this query?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by using ANSI join syntax, and then use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) to optimize the query:

```
select * 
from a
  inner join b on a.x = b.x OR a.y = b.y
  inner join c on b.z = c.z
```

Comment: The problem is that it seems that mysql can't use compound keys with OR

Comment: Right, but if you have separate indexes on each of a.x, a.y, b.x, and b.y then MySQL should be able to use an index merge for the join. Have you tried that?

Comment: I think I did. At one point I had 'every concievable combination' of indexes, but mysql was very reluctant choosing them.

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this

```
select 
   [your column names] 
from a
inner join b 
on a.x = b.x 
OR a.y = b.y
inner join c 
on b.z = c.z
```